# Spiking a message in OpenFire

Tags: openfire

I wanted to write a plugin in OpenFire to inspect incoming messages between users and possibly stop this message from ongoing to the target recipient.
I can write a plugin that implement PacketInterceptor, but is there an api that supports blocking this packet from being sent or possibly modifying the  body.

The rational for this is possibly offensive or illegal content.  The times we live in :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a packet filter created to do exactly this.

It can be found at https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/packetfilter/readme.html